Adding dead leaves to in ground compost
I've starting in-ground composting by digging a hole 10-12 inches deep, putting produce scraps in the hole, and then burying everything. Is there any issue with adding dead leaves in the hole along with the scraps?

There isn't any issue with that at all.  In fact, it will help your compost.
The compost needs a balance of high nitrogen and high carbon (sometimes called 'greens' and 'browns') to sustain life and chemistry.  Produce scraps are high-nitrogen (greens), so adding some high-carbon 'browns' like your dead leaves will help balance the pile.  A balanced pile will decompose more quickly, retain more nutrients, attract fewer pests, and smell less.

I don't have a pile. My compost is buried in the ground. Does this still apply?

@user2233706 Yup, all the same applies!

How much leaves should I add in comparison to the scraps?

@user2233706 Roughly speaking, you want 4x as much 'browns (dead leaves) as 'greens' (kitchen scraps) by weight.

Thanks, I'll collect the neighbors' leaves!

Note that leaves are fine for this approach (which is likely to be anaerobic anyway), but are terrible in a typical above ground pile as they mat and make it very hard to aerate the pile effectively, so the stock advice for leaves is to make leaf mould with them by piling them and wetting them down all by themselves. They decay, but don't exactly compost in the usual sense. The result is top-quality, though.

@Ecnerwal I have never experienced anything like that with leaves in my compost pile.  I can aerate it with a garden fork as normal, and they decompose with the rest of it.   I would also be surprised by a 12 inch deep hole going anaerobic, especially after the worms show up.
